# Non-simplicity of a Finite Group

Tags: group-theory

Prove that there is no simple group of order $9477=3^6\cdot 13$ using the action of $G$ by conjugation on the set of Sylow $3$-subgroups of $G$.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: By the Sylow's third theorem, the number of sylow 3-subgroups could be either 1 or 13. If it is one then we are done; otherwise, for any Sylow 3-subgroup say H, the index of normalizer of H in G equals 13; and hence the normalizer of each sylow 3-subgroup would be of order 3^6, which means each Sylow 3-subgroup precisely equals its normalizar in G. I'm @ this point now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's one Sylow 3-subgroup, then it's normal and $G$ isn't simple. The only other option is that there are 13 Sylow 3-subgroups. In this case, the action of $G$ by conjugation on the set of Sylow 3-subgroups gives rise to a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_{13}$. The homomorphism must be either injective or trivial. It cannot be trivial for otherwise the Sylow 3-subgroup would be normal.

However, this is a contradiction by Lagrange's theorem as 9477 doesn't divide 13!.

I hope this helps!

(Thanks to Daniel Fischer and DonAntonio for their comments below!)

Comment: Why would the homomorphism be injective? I don't see that. The conclusion that $G$ is not simple already follows from the homomorphism not being trivial, so we don't need injectivity.

Comment: The intersection of different Sylow 3-subgroups need not be trivial, consider $\mathbb{Z}_3\times G'$, all Sylow 3-subgroups contain the first factor.

Comment: @Daniel Oops. I was mistakenly thinking that the Sylow 3-subgroups have order $3$. (I was confusing them with the Sylow 13-subgroup.) Of course, you're right! Let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: Sure you can fix it, all you need is that the homomorphism can't be injective (because of the divisibility), hence its kernel is nontrivial and normal, and the kernel is not all of $G$ since the operation acts transitively.

Comment: Or, @AmiteshDatta, assume from the beginning that $\,G\,$ is simple which would mean the homomorphism $\,G\to S_{13}\,$ must be injective and there you have your contradiction. +1

Comment: @Daniel I've made the fix in my argument that you were suggesting. Thanks so much for your suggestions!

Comment: Thanks to you too @DonAntonio for your suggestion!